# postgreSQL - get most frequent value from many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table hobbies:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ hobby_1 | hobby_2 | hobby_3 +
+---------+---------+---------+
+ music   | soccer  | [null]  +
+ movies  | music   | cars    +
+ cats    | dogs    | music   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to get to most freuqent used value. The answer would be `music`

I know the query to get the most frequent value for one column:

```
SELECT hobby_1, COUNT(*) FROM hobbies
    GROUP BY hobby_1
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

But how to get the most frequent value when combining all columns.

Comment: Do you want the `null` to be counted or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unpivot the data.  Here is one method:

```
select h.hobby, count(*)
from ((select hobby_1 as hobby from hobbies) union all
      (select hobby_2 as hobby from hobbies) union all
      (select hobby_3 as hobby from hobbies) 
     ) h
group by h.hobby
order by count(*) desc;
```

However, you should really fix your data structure.  Having multiple columns only distinguished by a number is usually a sign of a problem with the data structure.  You should have a table with one row for each hobby.